# How do I program Ubuntu "grub:" to use 5.15.0.50 generic?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

The attached update-grub outputs shows that 5.15.0-50-generic (Ubuntu) is available.
After checking grub default file - output is too big to post here - I did not found any
"advanced options"  using 5.15.0.50. generic.
The grub default configuration should not be edited.

Is there a safe way to configure 5.15.0.50 as an "advanced option" in grub?

I will greatly appreciate a straight answer(s) to my question.

```
q5@q5-desktop:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for q5: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-46-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdb2
Found Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04) on /dev/sdb3
Found Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04) on /dev/sdb6
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdc17
Found Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04) on /dev/sdc3
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdc8
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdd7
Found Ubuntu 21.10 (21.10) on /dev/sde10
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde17
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde2
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde21
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde22
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde9
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdj2
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
q5@q5-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Ubuntu 5.15.0 50?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720754/where-is-ubuntu-5-15-0-50)

Comment: ^that's probably the previous post you're talking about.

Comment: You seem to have so many parallel installations of Ubuntu that there is a possibility that the GRUB that is updated by `update-grub` of this OS installation is not the GRUB that is started by default by the system firmware. That would explain why `update-grub` won't seem to make the 5.15.0.50 kernel available. To figure out if this is the case, please run `sudo efibootmgr -v` and add the output into your question.

Comment: To fully analyze the `sudo efibootmgr -v` output, it would be best to have the output of `lsblk -o +partuuid` too, please.

Comment: I would love to have only ONE discussion IF somebody tells / show me how to edit my original post. Back to the problem. There ar at lest three tools suggested / used to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straight answer, but is the best way to go.

The output of `os-prober` shows that there are 14 (!) installations of Ubuntu on the same machine, spread over 5 disks. This is the sign that someone has run an OS install multiple times and made a mess out of it.

```
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdb2
Found Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04) on /dev/sdb3
Found Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04) on /dev/sdb6
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdc17
Found Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04) on /dev/sdc3
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdc8
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdd7
Found Ubuntu 21.10 (21.10) on /dev/sde10
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde17
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde2
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde21
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde22
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sde9
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdj2
```

Hence, as @telcoM commented, it is likely that the `update-grub` command does not update the GRUB that is started by default at boot, but the GRUB in one of the other 13 installations.

In this case, it is **highly** recommended that you pick up a new machine and do a clear install of Ubuntu.  All these OS installs on this machine are unnecessary, take up space, and will immensely confuse you in all subsequent operations.

Comment: Tossing the entire machine seems a bit overkill. Just removing the superfluous installations with e.g. `gparted` would certainly suffice

Comment: Given the issue with the `update-grub` command, which probably hits on one of the other installs, I say we nuke the machine from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: I guess that by "nuke the machine" you mean "clear the drive". I want to point that out since I have witnessed people actually physically destroy their computers because of graphic descriptions. ;)

Comment: You are correct. That was actually a quote from Aliens (1986). ;)

Comment: I have made decent progress resolving this, I am now running 5.15.0.52 generic. I need to do more testing, however, since this forum is more interested in form and opinions  , I am not sure posting more about the issue would be of  benefits to the peanut gallery and Mr Higgins. It is closed anyway, thus showing the administration has  no interest in technical outcome.